# iOS 7 tab bar shown in wrong position

Tags: ios7, position, uitabbar

iOS 7, the tab bar does not appear in the bottom of the screen. 
[image]

I am just using a Tab Bar Controller in my StoryBoard. 
[image]

Update: I tried to set is location at the top of the screen programmatically (code below), it was correctly positioned there (at the top)

```
    UITabBar* tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
    tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,
                          tabBar.frame.size.width,
                          tabBar.frame.size.height);
```

But when I tried to set it at the bottom (code below) the bar totally disappeared!

```
    UITabBar* tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
    tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - tabBar.frame.size.height,
                          tabBar.frame.size.width,
                          tabBar.frame.size.height);
```

Any help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I should not answer my question but the solution is actually simple (After 1.5 hours of headache):
My tab view was part of a bigger project that already had a navigation controller that includes a tabBar. So all what i did is hiding this original tabBar so that mine can take its position.
Just this line:

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
```